# Subquery on a table with multiple primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

Here is my table:

```
t_task_event
------------
f_date
f_client_id
f_task_id
f_event
```

Each task can be created for several customers. Each event are registered in this table. As you can see, there is no event_id, that's very annoying, see why:

I want to get all task where the last event is "Error". I think that I should create a subquery to get all the last events of tasks regsitered for the customer. I have done it like this:

```
SELECT f_task_id, MAX( f_date ) AS f_date_max
FROM t_task_event
WHERE f_client_id =121
```

But with this result, how can I filter to keep only lines where the event is "Error"? Maybe is there a way to create a kind of key from the couple (f_task_id, f_date_max). Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    t.f_task_id
    ,t.f_client_id
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN t.f_event = 'Error' THEN t.f_date END) as MaxErrorDate
    ,MAX(t.f_date) As MaxEventDate
FROm
    t_task_event t
WHERE
    t.f_client_id = 121
GROUP BY
    t.f_task_id
    ,t.f_client_id
HAVING
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.f_event = 'Error' THEN t.f_date END) = MAX(t.f_date)
```

You should just be able to compare the result of a conditional aggregation to find Max Date of an Error and compare with `MAX(date)` to get only the events where the "latest" record is an error.

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly!